# Duplicate the Country Select Gem in Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

`Simple_form` gives me the

```
gem 'country_select'
```

which I use on my Edit Registration Form (And i Display it on a Show Page).

Now I want to use it with another controller too and display it on a different Show Page.
How do I separate or even include 2x the same gem?

e.g.

```
gem 'ships_to_country_select'
```

Comment: Not quite following you, why do you want to duplicate the gem?

Comment: If it works without duplicating the Gem then fine. I just need the Country select for 2 different inputs.